# CRC Reverse Engineer (Checksum from Machine / PC)

Tags: windows, serial-port, checksum, crc

I'm currently looking for on how to determine the CRC produced from the machine to PC (and vice-versa).
    The devices are communicating using serial communication or RS232 cable.

```
I do only have data to be able for us to create a program to be used for both devices.

The data given was from my boss and the program was corrupted. So we are trying for it to work out.

I hope everyone can help.

Thanks :)
```

Comment: You should consider at the very least, specifying what you _think_ is used as the src data for the crc calculation. You should also review the formatting of your data - its not exactly consistent or clear. What is `0D 0A` for instance? Is it 5 ascii charcaters, or is it 2 characters, whose values are expressed in hexadecimal? Do be aware, that before you can even start to guess at the CRC algo used, and the seed value used, you'll have to work out what you're calculating the CRC of. I.e - is it the CRC of any binary data sent, is it the CRC of the whole line, etc, etc. Big task ahead of you!!

Comment: I'm sorry for short info, yes the string withing " are characters / strings while the hex numbers are for ASCII table (e.g. 06 is ACK) . we cannot predict if it is the whole line or specific characters.

Comment: 0D 0A is carriage return and line feed in ascii..

Comment: Okay, that's some clarification - you should edit your post to include it.. I also query you on the following snippet from your post: `R "RC=23947" 0D 0A 1D` - am I correct in thinking that the `"` character is there for the reader. I.e this code sends the 8 ascii characters `RC=23497`, followed immediately by the 3 hex bytes `0D 0A 1D`. Your post is still really unclear. Think of the data as a map - a map that is still without a key and specified notation.

Comment: What happened to the data?  The original post was inconsistent in the use of quotes. Was it captured verbatim or typed in by a human (with errors and inconsistencies)?  Were the strings actually transmitted or are these decoded messages?  Where did these traces come from?  Can you still run the programs?

Comment: Please wait I'm editing the data for easier translations.

Comment: @pat These where the decoded message between a machine and PC. We only have a log file of this message.

Comment: It might also pay to get some information by reverse engineering and/or debugging the PC program.  If you're lucky, it might be fairly easy to locate tables used for the CRC or at least determine exactly what parts of the messages are subject to the CRC.

Comment: @MichaelBurr How to determine the tables used for CRC? I do realize what your idea is and I have different sets of samples. But I only see it maybe per line message for the CRC to compute..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence to use for the CRC calculation in your protocol is the ASCII string

- starting from the first printing character (e.g. the 'R' from REQ)
- until and including the '1E' in the calculation.
- It's a CRC with the following specs according to our [CRC calculator](http://www.docklight.de/manual/dl_calcchecksum.htm%E2%80%8E)

  CRC:16,1021,0000,0000,No,No

which means:

```
CRC width: 16 bit (of course)
polynomial: 1021 HEX (truncated CRC polynomial)
init value: 0000
final Xor applied: 0000
reflectedInput: No
reflectedOutput: No`
```

(If 'init value' were FFFF, it would be a "16 bit width CRC as designated by CCITT").

See also the [Docklight CRC glossary](http://www.docklight.de/manual/crc.htm) and the [Boost CRC library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/crc/index.html) on what the CRC terms mean plus sample code.

What I did is to write a small script that tries out the popular 16 bit CRCs on varying parts of the first simple "REQ=INI" command, and see if I end up with a sum of 4255. This failed, but instead of going a full brute force with trying all sorts of polynoms, I assumed that it was maybe just an oddball / flawed implementation of the known standards, and indeed succeeded with a variation of the CRC-CCITT.

Heres is some slow & easy C code (not table based!) to calculate all sorts of CRCs:

```
// Generic, not table-based CRC calculation 
// Based on and credits to the following:
// CRC tester v1.3 written on 4th of February 2003 by Sven Reifegerste (zorc/reflex)

unsigned long reflect (unsigned long crc, int bitnum) {

    // reflects the lower 'bitnum' bits of 'crc'
    unsigned long i, j=1, crcout=0;
    for (i=(unsigned long)1<<(bitnum-1); i; i>>=1) {
        if (crc & i) crcout|=j;
        j<<= 1;
    }
    return (crcout);
}    

calcCRC(
    const int width, const unsigned long polynominal, const unsigned long initialRemainder, 
    const unsigned long finalXOR, const int reflectedInput, const int reflectedOutput, 
    const unsigned char message[], const long startIndex, const long endIndex) 
{ 
    // Ensure the width is in range: 1-32 bits
    assert(width >= 1 && width <= 32);  
    // some constant parameters used
    const bool b_refInput = (reflectedInput > 0); 
    const bool b_refOutput = (reflectedOutput > 0); 
    const unsigned long crcmask = ((((unsigned long)1<<(width-1))-1)<<1)|1;
    const unsigned long crchighbit = (unsigned long)1<<(width-1);

    unsigned long j, c, bit;
    unsigned long crc = initialRemainder;

    for (long msgIndex = startIndex; msgIndex <= endIndex; ++msgIndex) {
        c = (unsigned long)message[msgIndex];
        if (b_refInput) c = reflect(c, 8);
        for (j=0x80; j; j>>=1) {
            bit = crc & crchighbit;
            crc<<= 1;
            if (c & j) bit^= crchighbit;
            if (bit) crc^= polynominal;
        }
    }   
    if (b_refOutput) crc=reflect(crc, width);
    crc^= finalXOR;
    crc&= crcmask;
    return(crc);
}
```

With this code and the CRCs specs listed above, I have been able to re-calculate the following three sample CRCs:

```
10.03.2014 22:20:57.109 [TX] - REQ=INI<CR><LF>
<RS>CRC=4255<CR><LF>
<GS>
10.03.2014 22:20:57.731 [TX] - ANS=INI<CR><LF>
STATUS=0<CR><LF>
<RS>CRC=57654<CR><LF>
<GS>
10.03.2014 22:20:59.323 [TX] - ANS=INI<CR><LF>
STATUS=0<CR><LF>
MID="CTL1"<CR><LF>
DEF="DTLREQ";1025<CR><LF>
INFO=0<CR><LF>
<RS>CRC=1683<CR><LF>
<GS>
```

I failed on the very complex one with the `DEF=` parts - probably didn't understand the character sequence correctly.

The Docklight script I used to reverse engineer this:

```
Sub crcReverseEngineer()
    Dim crctypes(7)

    crctypes(0) = "CRC:16,1021,FFFF,0000" ' CCITT
    crctypes(1) = "CRC:16,8005,0000,0000" ' CRC-16
    crctypes(2) = "CRC:16,8005,FFFF,0000" ' CRC-MODBUS

    ' lets try also some nonstandard variations with different init and final Xor, but stick
    ' to the known two polynoms.

    crctypes(3) = "CRC:16,1021,FFFF,FFFF"
    crctypes(4) = "CRC:16,1021,0000,FFFF"
    crctypes(5) = "CRC:16,1021,0000,0000"

    crctypes(6) = "CRC:16,8005,FFFF,FFFF"
    crctypes(7) = "CRC:16,8005,FFFF,0000"

    crcString = "06 1C 52 45 51 3D 49 4E 49 0D 0A 1E 43 52 43 3D 30 30 30 30 0D 0A 1D"

    For reflectedInOrOut = 0 To 3
        For cType = 0 To 7
            crcSpec = crctypes(cType) & "," & IIf(reflectedInOrOut Mod 2 = 1, "Yes", "No") & "," & IIf(reflectedInOrOut > 1, "Yes", "No")
            For cStart = 1 To 3
                For cEnd = 9 To (Len(crcString) + 1) / 3
                    subDataString = Mid(crcString, (cStart - 1) * 3 + 1, (cEnd - cStart + 1) * 3)
                    result = DL.CalcChecksum(crcSpec, subDataString, "H")
                    resultInt = CLng("&h" + Left(result, 2)) * 256 + CLng("&h" + Right(result, 2))
                    If resultInt = 4255 Then
                        DL.AddComment "Found it!"
                        DL.AddComment "sequence:   " & subDataString
                        DL.AddComment "CRC spec:   " & crcSpec
                        DL.AddComment "CRC result: " & result & " (Integer = " & resultInt & ")"
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Public Function IIf(blnExpression, vTrueResult, vFalseResult)
  If blnExpression Then
    IIf = vTrueResult
  Else
    IIf = vFalseResult
  End If
End Function
```

Hope this helps and I'm happy to provide extra information or clarify details.

Comment: Nice description of your approach and analysis. I wish I could upvote more.

Comment: @OliverHeggelbacher That was very amazing..I have no idea that there would be serial monitor and scripting program. May I ask do I need full license of the program to test the sample code you've given..

Comment: @OliverHeggelbacher - Regarding the "DEF= parts", the number is incremental for each login on machine. But the PC can determine the next number to be given / send to machine.

Comment: @user3387293. Thanks. Look, for calculating the crc in your own code you really need only the C code (or some similar example, like from the Boost libraries) and call it with the arguments I found out. Something like calcCRC(16, 0x1021 , 0, 0, 0, 0, <myMsg>, 0, <msgLen>). But I can also msg you (or even upload) the Docklight script / project as a file. Any predefined script / project can run in Docklight in the free (evaluation), no time limits. You just cannot modify the script.

Comment: @user3387293. Or use an [online CRC calculator](http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html), I'm just not sure if it can handle the ASCII control characters.

Comment: @user3387293. I thought about it - I can make you an example which works in the free (evaluation) version and which will allow you to send any own command to your device, and Docklight will automatically calculate and add the CRC to the command you want to send. It's a great test for how good our tool works for these reverse engineering jobs, and where we maybe should improve things, so I am happy to provide a demo. Please allow me one day or so for this.

Comment: @OliveHeggelbacher - That would've be great if I can test the code using Docklight and the script you mentioned. If you wanted I can send more samples but it will be thru pm only.

Comment: @OliveHeggelbacher - I'm grateful that there is a program that you've made solely for debugging / decoding with serial communication. I will try also using the BoostC+ and replicate the sample you've given. Once again thank you for your great effort. :)

Comment: @user3387293 I'll put it up. BTW I also found there are other reverse-engineering helpers. See this Python based [CRC Tool Kit](https://github.com/henryk/ctk) or this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438495)

Comment: I'm having hard time to compile the sample programs and links you've given. I cannot work out the errors. Still I'll pursue the knowledge you've shared and will not waste it. I'm testing the Python and stuck with print "Will Solve", resource from GitHub. Also I'm testing the C++ code, may I confirm the code you've given is C++? Thank you.

Comment: @OliverHeggelbacher May I know what did you use startIndex and endIndex for the 1st program you've given. I'm currently using the program with Dev-C++.

Comment: @user3387293 Check the [original C example from Sven Reifegerste](http://zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crctester.c) i used as a base.

startindex/endIndex is only some extra I need in Docklight to calculate on only a PART of the message, you don't need to use it that way. 

Just make sure you calculate on the correct part of your message. First character for the calculation is the first text character, not the "06 1C". Last character is the "1E".

Comment: @OliverHeggelbacher Ok i've been using the samples codes in Dev-C++ and I'm happy that atleast it is working now. I'm trying to decode the code you've given. May I ask if I can use the Docklight script?..if it is OK. Still greatly appreciated your effort and time. Thanks!

Comment: Here is my [Docklight CRC Reverse Engineering script](http://docklight.de/examples/extras/CrcReverseEngineeringExample.zip). It works with the (Docklight Scripting)[http://docklight.de/download/Docklight_Scripting.zip] software in evaluation mode. No license required. If you open the project file (.ptp), you will see additional information and comments.

Comment: @user3387293 if the CRC works for you, can you mark my answer as "accepted"? Thanks. See the above comment for the Docklight scripts you asked for.

Comment: @OliverHeggelbacher Thanks mate. I will continue using your sample docklight program and ideas :)

Comment: Updated and improved [CRC reverse engineering example](http://docklight.de/exampleFiles/extras/CrcReverseEngineeringExample.zip). Solves also similar [Stackoverflow question 29850992](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850992/serial-rs232-communication-checksums)